# Which country am I thinking of?

Tags: lateral-thinking, rebus, computer-puzzle, geography

*Fill in the gaps with the answers of the rebuses, and then answer the question: Which country am I thinking of?*

**It's**

> → 2 ↓↲

**And they will be the**

```
8 - 3 = 5
        ^
--------------------
   __    → e
 _/__)  ↑  ↓
(8|)_}}- 1W0
 ¯\__)

--------------------
  _______
 /  12   \
|    |    |
|9   | / 3|
|         |
|         |
 \___6___/
 _____________________________
|  _  _     _   _      _   _  |
| | | _| o | | | |  o | |  _| |
| |_||_  o |_| |_|  o |_| |_  |
|_____________________________|
```

> - s = ?

**to enjoy the**

```
//C#
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class Program{
    static void Main(){
        new Program();
    }

    public Program(){
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.Year + "'s "
          + Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width + "x" + Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
    }
}
```

Hint for 2 & 3

> According to / Source:
>
>  [805304](http://s21.postimg.org/fyon9pln7/country.gif)

Hint for 3 (mainly for the non software developers among us)

> Example output:
>  `2016's 1920x1200`

Hint (number of separate words the rebuses imply):

1. > Four (or three)
2. > One
3. > Three

Please be complete in your answer.

Comment: I have a hard time discerning the first drawing in your second rebus. Is it a fly? a plane? batman?

Comment: It's clearly a graffiti bumblebee

Comment: @fffred look at the markdown source of the answer, there appears to be a hidden image link to explain what that is.

Comment: @fffred _psydsigner_ has the correct interpretation in his answer, it's a bee, [according to Joan Stark](http://www.ascii-code.com/ascii-art/animals/insects/bees.php)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My guess:

> New Zealand

Why?

Clue 1:

> It's... next to Down Under (Australia)

Clue 2:

> And they will be the... second

This one is the hardest, and I didn't know what to do with the first two. But then I realized:

> "The difference" "Bee-tween" "2:00" and "2:00:02" = "2 seconds" -s (- "seconds") = "2" = "second"

Clue 3:

> To enjoy the... New Year's Resolution

But why?

> On New Year's day, New Zealand is on its DST, which moves it from UTC+12 to UTC+13, one hour behind +14 Kiribati, along with several other countries. But, because the Chatham Islands are +¾ to the rest of New Zealand, part of New Zealand actually enters the new year in uncontested second place.

Comment: How did you get that for clue 2?

Comment: @f'' I was kinda grasping at straws with  with the first two pictures of clue 2. I know I had gotten it wrong now because I got my time backwards.

Comment: @f'' I'm switching back to my original mental answer.

Comment: what does this have to do with the `synt bs vaqvn`

Comment: Added aha moment info for clue 2.

Comment: `inahngh` isn't the second though. The first couple are `fnzbn` and part of `xvevongv` (+14), then the `pungunz vfynaqf` of `arj mrnynaq` (+13¾), then `gbatn`, another part of `xvevongv`, and the rest of `arj mrnynaq` (+13).

Comment: @question_asker That still has me confused

Comment: @f'' I was thinking `frpbaq gvzrmbar`; however, I was not aware that there were any >+12.

Comment: @pydsigner same here - I wasn't trying to correct you or anything, your answer makes sense to me

Comment: @question_asker I'm wondering if it's supposed to be `n greevgbel bs vaqvn`, the question specifies "country" though.

Comment: @pydsigner Yeah, that seems possible, and even likely, given the rest of the clues. Unless we're not interpreting it right, somehow.

Comment: Very nice! +1 All three clues are entirely correct. The answer not though (although I guess multiple answers are possible here..) You can use the first of the three hints to figure out the correct country I had in mind. EDIT: I see you gave the correct answer already in the past, but you changed it. xD (Hint 1 can still be used to determine why.)

Comment: Good job. How did you get the `gjrra` bit?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Is my explanation complete now?

Comment: @pydsigner I've accepted the answer, since all three clues & the answer are correct now. As for the first hint: It's the Indian flag. If you google "india 805304" you'll get the following hit on the first page: http://www.india.com/whatever/1dayto2016-do-you-know-which-is-the-first-country-to-celebrate-the-new-year-805304/ Here they have New Zealand on the **_second_** place, which is the source I've used.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Ah ok. I tried googling just the number and then the number with some other stuff but never "india" with the number.

Comment: @HumphreyTriscuit Extrapolation, to be honest. The arrow isn't quite coming down between anything, although maybe it's that the W is between the 1 and the 0.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen dang, I tried that but I didn't get that result. Presumably because Google result vary by geography?

Comment: @HumphreyTriscuit Likewise here, at least not on the first page.

Comment: @HumphreyTriscuit Ah, could be. [Here is a screenshot of my search results](http://s18.postimg.org/k12cn70bt/india_805304.png) Hadn't thought of Google's complex search algorithm that differs based on previous search terms, language, and who knows what else.. Ah well, _pydsigner_ managed to get the answer and clues correct. This was my very first rebus ever, so it wasn't that bad, was it?

Answer (score 3):

Partial answer:

> #3 seems to mean "New Year's resolution"